# S3 Eventual consistency: Is it safe to delete an object while there's an outstanding copy for it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm issuing an S3 CopyObject (aka PUT copy) from a source bucket that is different than the destination bucket. I'm wondering if it's safe to delete the source after CopyObject has returned OK to the REST client. By "safe", I mean that the destination object will *eventually* show up, and that it will initially contain *all* of the data available at the time the copy was issued.

Corruption in the copy is perhaps unlikely (given that most operations are atomic), but the two operations cancelling each other *might* be possible. I wish the docs were slightly more fleshed out wrt to [eventual consistency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html).

(in my scenario, nothing's writing to the source nor destination key in the interim. and the same client does the copy and delete).

e.g. synchronous pseudocode:

```
try:

    # make sure this is a create. read-after-create consistency
    my_tmpname = "new_tempfile" + uuid4()
    s3_put(data, "s3://my-bucket1/" + my_tmpname)

    ...

    # copy it to its final location
    s3_copy("s3://my-bucket1/new_tempfile", "s3://my-bucket2/final_location")
finally:
    # Cleanup temp file.
    #
    # Can this delete interfere with the copy in flight?
    # e.g. Should one wait a few seconds/minutes?
    # e.g. Should one ensure that the target exists before deleting source?
    s3_delete("s3://my-bucket/new_tempfile")
```

Comment: its a synchronous call. As long as you do not delete source files from outside the script while copy is in-progress, you will be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly safe to delete an object immediately after a successful copy operation using that object as the source object, because copy operations are not asynchronous.

The copy request does not return until the operation has either succeeded or failed.

> To help better ensure data durability, Amazon S3 *PUT* and *PUT Object copy* operations synchronously store your data across multiple facilities before returning `SUCCESS`.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DataDurability.html

The consistency model in S3 is related only to the visibility of objects, not the durability of their storage.

Comment: So, definitely start the delete after the copy is completed. Good to know that PUT and PUT-COPY are synchronous!

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 features read-after-write consistency for PUTs and the copy case you exemplified:

> **Amazon S3 Data Consistency Model**
>
> Amazon S3 provides read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new
>   objects in your S3 bucket in all regions with one caveat. The caveat
>   is that if you make a HEAD or GET request to the key name (to find if
>   the object exists) before creating the object, Amazon S3 provides
>   eventual consistency for read-after-write.

Check the documentation for consistency of the other operations.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html

Comment: Most of the examples on that page cover consistency done over the same key however (e.g. read-after-write of the same key).